# Create a variable of type UIView that conforms a protocol in swift

Tags: ios, swift

Inside a class, I want to add a variable of type UIView, which conforms to the following protocol:

```swift
public protocol Shadow: UIView {
    func applyShadow()
}

public extension Shadow {
    func applyShadow() {
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 16
        ...
    }
}
```

To then be able to do something like this :

```swift
private lazy var shadowView: Shadow = UIView()
shadowView.applyShadow()
```

I want to do this, so I don't have to bring that function `applyShadow()` to my class and have repeated code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, there are 2 ways to do this. One is having a protocol `Shadow` then creating a concrete class to conform to `Shadow` protocol as below

```
public protocol Shadow: UIView {
    func applyShadow()
}

public extension Shadow {
    func applyShadow() {
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 16
    }
}

// re-use Shadow protocol 
//this is a concrete class that conforms to Shadow protocol 
class Title: UIView, Shadow {}


class Card: UIView {
   private lazy var oneVariable: Title = {
        let view = Title()
        view.applyShadow()
        return view
    }()
}
```

Or you can create an extension of UIView in `Shadow` class

```
class Shadow: UIView {}

extension UIView {
    func applyShadow() {
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 16
    }
}
```

Comment: Of course I understand both solutions, but it is not what I am looking for. 

What I want is that ONE VARIABLE conforms to my protocol.

Comment: Both solution are good : you must define a type that conform to the protocol to define variable using this protocol, or extend existing type with it. You can’t say I want a variable of one type but add the protocol to that variable only.